# PDO insert into inserting two rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rows

My request PDO Insert into is inserting two rows in my table, How can i solve it please ?
This is my scripts

```
 try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX;charset=utf8', 'XXX', 'XXX');
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO Commentaires(pseudo, commentaire, date_comment, id_video) VALUES(:pseudo, :commentaire, :date_comment, :id_video)');

    $req->execute(array(
        'pseudo'=>$_POST['pseudo'],
        'commentaire'=>$_POST['comment'],
        'date_comment'=> $today,
        'id_video'=>$id));

    $req->execute();
    $req->closeCursor();
    header('Location: read.php?min='.$min.'&id='.$id);
```

Comment: You're calling `$req->execute()` twice, that's why it's inserting two rows. Remove the second call.

Comment: if these are valid credentials for your live database you ought really to change them asap!

Comment: @rickdenhaan Hmm, that's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Just checked the PDO source code. When it gets an array argument, it loops over it calling `bindParam` or `bindValue` (not sure, it's C code calling internal functions), then it falls through to the code that uses bound parameters.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Maybe they didn't document it because they don't want to commit to this implementation. But the fact that you don't get an error when calling with no arguments and not having called bindXXX explicitly feels like a bug if it's not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove second execution.

```php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX;charset=utf8', 'XXX', 'XXX');
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$min = $_POST['min'];
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO Commentaires(pseudo, commentaire, date_comment, id_video) VALUES(:pseudo, :commentaire, :date_comment, :id_video)');

$req->execute([
    'pseudo'=> $_POST['pseudo'],
    'commentaire'=> $_POST['comment'],
    'date_comment'=> $today,
    'id_video'=> $id
]);

$req->closeCursor();
```

**Edit:** Removed redirect code.

Comment: The second execution should get an error because it's missing the parameter array, so it can't be causing the double entries.

Comment: You're welcome. Please change your database user and password because it has exposed.